# sc.exe how to set up the description for the windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am using sc.exe command to install C# windows service.

```
C:Windows\System32> sc.exe Create "TestService1" binPath= "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\TestService1" DisplayName= "TestWindowsService1"
```

It created service. I was able to start the service. Many Instances I was able to create using sc.exe command

Looking at **Services**

Name       |               **Description**  |     Status  |  Start type | Log on As

Description section is blank, I would like to set the descriptionm, Any way to set up description for the service using sc.exe commmand?

Comment: After you create the service, call "sc <server> description [service name] [description]" to set the description.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You need to call sc again to set the description. For example:

```
sc description TestService1 "This is the description of the service.."
```

For more information, see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742069.aspx).

Comment: I find it weird that it wouldn't be a parameter in the create command.  This works though, thanks.  I'm hoping in the future MS beefs up the Worker Service template to allow these things to be set through code rather than command line.

Comment: For those who would like to do this programmatically: `ChangeServiceConfig2A( service, SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, &desc );`

Answer (score 18):

Is not

```
sc description TestService1 "TestService1"
```

as per documentation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742069.aspx  ?

Answer (score 3):

For those experiencing "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument" (PositionalParameterNotFound) error while trying to use the "sc description" command, replace sc with sc.exe. Apparently it fixes the problem, although the "sc create" command works as expected, without .exe

Comment: It works after replacing sc with sc.exe!

Comment: ^^ especially if you are using powershell ;)  since sc is an alias for another command

Answer (score 2):

The command set description call after "sc create service_name...":

```
sc description service_name "Service descriptions"
```